# Tomcat SSL: TLS vs ALL

Tags: tomcat, ssl, apr

What is the best value for SSLProtocol parameter in Tomcat APR config?
Docs says: "Protocol which may be used for communicating with clients. The default is "all", with other acceptable values being "SSLv2", "SSLv3", "TLSv1", and "SSLv2+SSLv3"."

At first I've made a mistake and actually had SSL2 enabled which caused problems to many clients like "SSL2 not supported, you must switch to TLS".
So I changed that to "TLSv1" and it was OK till I've got some problems with remote http requests.

Finally I changed the value to "all" (default). Is it correct? Or SSL2 must be disabled?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default in the Sun JRE is to use SSLv2 for the initial handshake, and then "upgrade" to either SSLv3, or TLSv1.  Unless you have good reason not to, I would stick with the default.

Answer (score 0):

I use `SSLv3+TLSv1`, so that SSLv2 is disabled (it has a number of security problems and is not PCI-DSS compliant), but clients can choose to use either SSLv3 or TLSv1, which is sufficiently secure and is supported by practically every modern client.

Comment: Not so.  TLSv1.0 is not PCI-DSS compliant and that's what you get when you do it this way.